# jquery ajax call returns double results

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling an page using ajax. On that page there are some form elements. When save is pressed on the form elements my formcheck script fires off saying that a field is empty when it is not. After a bunch of head bashing I figured out that for some reason, the page is being duplicated. Even though i can't see the duplicate on my site, the code does see it and that's why it sees an empty text field even though I already filled it out. How do i go about killing this duplicate page? Here's my page. FYI, it goes through a loop because I'm cloning the fields and i need to check all the fields generated.

formcheck code

```
  $(document).on('click','#but_uploadSubmitT',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    save = true; // reset the save variable before the loop

    $('.carrier').each(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      console.log('*** class '+value);

        if(value==''){
            alert('Please enter a Carrier/Mode/Account before saving');
            save = false;
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(save){
      $('#uploadSpinner').show();
      $('#uploadFormT').submit();
    }
  });
```

here's the page being loaded with ajax (just the relevant section):

```
    <td><input name="carrier" type="text" id="carrier" style="width:225px;" class="commas carrier"></td>
```

Ajax call:

```
  $(document).on('click','#import', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-lg modal-sm');

    $('.mHeader').html('<h3>Upload File <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="display:none" id="uploadSpinner"></i></h3>');

    $('.mBody').load('/ajax/upload.asp?clientID=5',function(){

      $('.mFooter').html($('#mFooterC').html()); 

    });

    $('#mWindow').modal();
```

Comment: Where is the AJAX call?

Comment: BTW, jquery `.size()` is deprecated. You should use `$('.carrier').length`.

Comment: what is #but_uploadSubmitT? If this input[type=submit], then when you click you get two events

Comment: <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="but_uploadSubmitT"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</a>.. not an input

Comment: `$('.mFooter').html($('#mFooterC').html());` makes a duplicate of all the HTML in `#mFooterC`. Is that where `.carrier` is?

Comment: no it is not.... carrier is in .mBody.